# Set NSLayoutConstraint of view to top right

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm at wits end trying to figure this out. In CSS, you can do something like this:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

In Swift, I am using the programatic interface to set layout constraints of an image. It looks like this:

```
let img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "my-image"))
img.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
mainScrollView.addSubview(img)
mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Width,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil,            attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Height,   relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil,            attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Top,      relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .Top,            multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .Trailing,       multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

However for some bizarre reason it respects the width and height layout constraints, even the top one. but it's basically off screen to the left by 50. If I set the last `.Trailing` constant to `50`, it actually moves it into view at the top left (yes I'm very confused by this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints should be applied to the view which is the nearest common ancestors of the view involved in the constraint. So I can see two errors in the code you posted:

1. if you are setting the `height` or the `width` of a view, the view itself is the nearest common ancestor view so the constraint should be applied directly to it. So your code should be:

   ```
   item.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
   item.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
   ```
2. Since the views involved in this constraint:

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
   ```

   are one the subview of the other, it should be applied to the parent view:

   ```
   mainView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)))
   ```

Regarding the problem with the `Trailing` attribute you should considering that when you are adding a constraint you are defining this formula:

```
item1.attribute = item2.attribute + constant
```

So if you are defining a constraint where both the attributes are `Trailing` you should to use a negative constant to have one view inside the other:

```
--------------------------
View1                    |
-------------            |
View2       |  - (-50) - |
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation! The formula really makes it much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it the way that doesn't involve code? Using the buttons on the bottom right of the story board view?

Comment: I'm familiar with the interface builder options. however this is a situation where i've built a number of views programatically so I need to set their positions in code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to set it to top right with width and height both 50? Maybe you can do it like this:

```
let img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "my-image"))
img.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
mainScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[img(50)]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["img" : img]))
mainScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[img(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["img" : img]))
```

Comment: strange. no dice there either.

Comment: Have you test that the [mainView] at the right position?

Comment: there was a typo in the question -- they are all `mainScrollView`. nevertheless, the constraints are all being set on the `img`. Anyhow, the constraints on the `mainScrollView` is set to be all `0` (zero's) for top, leading, trailing, and bottom — so it takes up the entire view.

Comment: For my testing, it seems that, mainView caused this error, if i set the mainView's frame without constraints ,it works well. I don't know why right now

Comment: that's so strange. Wonder what causes it to do that.

Comment: Maybe, this is a bug for swift, I tested it with OC, it works well, nothing wrong happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87627/discussion-between-ded-and-siam).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that unlike standard views, constraints between a scroll view and its subviews don't dictate the size of the subviews, but rather *the `contentSize` of the scroll view.* This may seem curious, but it's actually a wonderful feature, getting us out of the business of calculating `contentSize` manually. For more information, see [Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

But this means that in order to dictate the size of a subview within a scroll view, you actually have to reference something *outside* of the scroll view (e.g. the view controller's main `view`).

So you can place a "container" view inside the scroll view and put the image view in the upper right corner of that. And then you can define the container to be the width of the main view. That way you're accomplishing both goals, dictating the width of the contents of the the scroll view, and dictating the placement of the image view within that:

```
// define the container inside the scroll view

let containerView = UIView()
containerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

// put the imageView in the container

let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "my-image"))
imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
containerView.addSubview(imageView)

let views = ["containerView" : containerView, "view" : view, "imageView" : imageView]

// constraints for the container

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[containerView(==view)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[containerView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

// define the imageview constraints

containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[imageView(==50)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[imageView(==50)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Comment: I'm so so sorry there was a typo in the main question. There is only the main `view`, then `mainScrollView`. I accidentally typed `mainView` which does not exist. Thus: `view` > `mainScrollView` > `img`

Comment: @ded - Lol. That's hilarious because having a view in between the scroll view and the image view is how you actually solve this problem. I've revised my answer to make that more clear. The main point of my answer still stands, that you need something in there to say that the contents of the scroll view are equal to the width of the main view. You may have defined constraints that dictate the `frame` of the scroll view, but you need something to dictate the width of the `contentSize`, too.